# Is there a way to "print" (via c# code) from an Asp.Net MVC application by using the printer(s) installed on the application's hosted server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, printing, server, printers

My company has its own server on which we have installed a few printers. The Asp.Net MVC application is running on the same server. My question is, how can I print to one of the installed printers on the server FROM the application? I don't want the print request to originate from the client, but from the host.

I have already tried a few variations of code using the "PrintServer" and "PrintQueue" classes. But I can't seem to get anything to print remotely, the print Queue is showing no activity after the programs run. The "Options" below are various ways I've been experimenting with GETTING the list(s) of Printers to populate a dropdown. However, all but option 4 only get Printers that are installed locally. I need a way to Populate a list of Server Installed Printers (done, via option 4), then Select that Printer and be able to print to it (still a mystery).

Thanks ahead of time my fellow Knights of the Code!

And please, don't be unkind. :)

```
// GET: View
public ActionResult Index()
{      
  //BEGIN PRINTING AREA...
  //THIS SECTION IS FOR GETTING A LIST OF PRINTERS TO PRINT FROM...
  //OPTION 1 PRINTING...
  List<SelectListItem> optOnePrinters = new List<SelectListItem>();
  var server = new PrintServer();
  var queues = server.GetPrintQueues(new[]
  { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Shared, EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections });
  foreach (var item in queues)
  {
    if(!optOnePrinters.Any(a=>a.Text == item.FullName))
    {
      optOnePrinters.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item.FullName, Value = item.ShareName });
    }
  }
  ViewData["PrinterListOptOne"] = optOnePrinters;

  //OPTION 2 PRINTING...
  List<SelectListItem> optTwoPrinters = new List<SelectListItem>();
  foreach (string sPrinters in System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
  {
    optTwoPrinters.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text=sPrinters, Value=sPrinters });
  }
  ViewData["PrinterListOptTwo"] = optTwoPrinters;

  //OPTION 3 PRINTING...
  List<SelectListItem> optThreePrinters = new List<SelectListItem>();
  System.Management.ManagementScope objMS =
      new System.Management.ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath);
  objMS.Connect();

  SelectQuery objQuery = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");
  ManagementObjectSearcher objMOS = new ManagementObjectSearcher(objMS, objQuery);
  System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMOS.Get();

  foreach (ManagementObject Printers in objMOC)
  {

    if (Convert.ToBoolean(Printers["Local"]))     // ALL LOCAL PRINTERS.
    {
      optThreePrinters.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = Printers["DeviceID"] != null ? "(Local)" + (string)Printers["Name"] + ": " + (string)Printers["DeviceID"] : "(Local)" + (string)Printers["Name"], Value = (string)Printers["Name"] });
    }
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(Printers["Network"]))     // ALL NETWORK PRINTERS.
    {
      //Get list of Printer Properties...
      //foreach (PropertyData property in Printers.Properties)
      //{
      //  optThreePrinters.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text= property.Value == null ? property.Name : property.Name + ": " + property.Value.ToString(), Value=property.Value == null? property.Name: property.Value.ToString() });
      optThreePrinters.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "(Network)" + Printers["PortName"] !=null ? (string)Printers["Name"] + ": " + (string)Printers["PortName"] : (string)Printers["Name"], Value = (string)Printers["Name"] });
    }
  }
  ViewData["PrinterListOptThree"] = optThreePrinters;

  //OPTION 4 PRINTING...
  // Create a PrintServer
  // "theServer" must be a print server to which the user has full print access.
  List<SelectListItem> optFourPrinters = new List<SelectListItem>();

  PrintServer myPrintServer = new PrintServer(@"\\ServerName");
  // List the print server's queues
  PrintQueueCollection myPrintQueues = myPrintServer.GetPrintQueues();
  foreach (PrintQueue pq in myPrintQueues)
  {
    optFourPrinters.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = pq.Name, Value = pq.Name });
  }
  ViewData["PrinterListOptFour"] = optFourPrinters;
  return View();
}

  //END PRINTING...

//BEGIN PRINT FUNCTIONS ON DropDown SELECT FROM VIEW...
public ActionResult Print(string PrinterName)
{
  Feedback f = new Feedback();
  PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
  doc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = PrinterName;
  doc.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = "AEMSNet_TestPrint";
  doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintHandler);
  doc.Print();

  f.Success = true;
  f.Type = FeedbackType.Success;
  f.SuccessMsg = "Successfully Printing!";
  return Json(f, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

private void PrintHandler(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ppeArgs)
{      
  Font FontNormal = new Font("Verdana", 9);
  Graphics g = ppeArgs.Graphics;      
  g.DrawString("Greetings from the Home Controller.", FontNormal, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(10.0F, 100.0F, 750.0F, 80.0F), new StringFormat());           
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that the user that runs the server side application has print permissions?

Comment: Hi @Ralf, yes, the application has access to network resources. Thanks for your inquiry!